# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and CAMERA feature

Tags: android, camera, android-manifest

I'm using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to request camera app to take a photo.
According to [official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) if my app uses camera feature but doesn't require it for correct functioning, following should be left in manifest

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="false" />
    ... 
</manifest>
```

I don't really get what is the idea of having those lines in manifest, isn't it just the same without having this **not** required feature.

I would like to know what is the point to write this ? Can I safely skip this from manifest ?

Doesn't matter if I have the feature listed in manifest, I'll still be able to check it during run-time, correct `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the same. As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) say:

> The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it.

This means that it would be *nice* to have that feature, but the app will still work without it. For example, an app that can take pictures but that does not need it as part of its normal operation would use the `required=false` for the camera.

You might ask that through code, yes. But the problem is that some `permissions` [imply](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#implicit) that you require some particular hardware:

> If an application requests hardware-related permissions, Google Play assumes that the application uses the underlying hardware features and therefore requires those features, even though there might be no corresponding to  declarations. For such permissions, Google Play adds the underlying hardware features to the metadata that it stores for the application and sets up filters for them.
>
> For example, if an application requests the CAMERA permission but does not declare a  element for android.hardware.camera, Google Play considers that the application requires a camera and should not be shown to users whose devices do not offer a camera.

So if you want to use some features but not others, and you are including the permission, you might want to declare that your app does not **really** requires the presence of a certain device feature.

Comment: For taking a photo with intent the permissions is not required to be written in manifest.

Comment: That was just an example with the camera, take my answer as a general explanation of why it exists, and how the features and permissions interact together.

Comment: Thanks for general clearance. For my simple case, looks like they are the same. Makes no sense to have feature explicitly defined in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

From Android docs:

> The purpose of a  declaration is to inform any external
>   entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your
>   application depends.
>
> In general, you should always make sure to declare 
>   elements for all of the features that your application requires

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="false" />
```

If required = "false" is given in manifest then app uses a camera but it’s not mandatory for the application to work, and all device can install app from play store whether device has camera feature or not.

if required = "true" is given in manifest then device which has camera feature can only use app other devices which do not have camera feature not able to install from google play store.

This allows Google Play Store to filter out apps for devices that don’t have their required features.

I hope it helps!